# How to invoke onMount() before executing other code in script setup?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I am trying to load some settings in onMount() function but it does not execute the onMount() first.

The other code inside script setup is executing and failing because the settings are not present. What is the correct way to load settings first inside script setup? Thanks for any suggestions.

```
<script setup>

  import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
    import { useAccountStore } from '../stores/account.store'
    import { defineProps, reactive, ref, computed, onBeforeMount } from "vue";
    import { useLoading } from 'vue-loading-overlay';

    const accountStore = useAccountStore()

    const { account, error, accountsettings } = storeToRefs(accountStore)

    const props = defineProps({
        id: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
    });

    const settings = accountsettings.value;

    let type = settings.type;

    //Other functions
    
    
    async function load() {

        await accountStore.loadSettings();

        if (props.id) {
            await accountStore.loadAccount(props.id);
        }
       
    };
    
     onMount(() => {
     
        console.log('mounting...');
        load();
    });
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot run `OnMount` before `Setup`.
There is a lifecycle rule and the first initialization is `setup`. The `onMounted` hook can be used to run code after the component has finished the initial rendering and created the DOM nodes.

For a better understanding, please have a look at the initialization life cycle diagram:

[image: Lifecycle initialization diagram]

You must redesign your component taking into account that Setup is the first initialization.

Looking at your code, to load your settings, you could simply call `await load()` at the end of your `setup` script. It will run at the end of your initialization and you should avoid any errors. Like that, you can delete the hook `onMount`.